# suggestions to swap animated gifs without having them freeze?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm working on a site that uses animated graphs do display information. all of the graphs are animated gifs. there is one spot for the animated graphs, and often times the graphs have multiple parts. so the main functionality is being able to click the graph, have it play once, click the graph again, and the second part play, and so on, until it gets to the last part and plays over again.

the problem is that sometimes the graphs freeze or don't load. they are only supposed to play through once each time they are clicked. often times the graph will switch to the next one, but it will be frozen with no way to get it to play.

i tried loading a blank src before loading the new graph, and it seems to stop the gifs from freezing, but that causes and flash of a broken image before the new graph loads.

this is the code i'm using to swap graph...

```
 $('.rightPostContent img').click(function(){           
        imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');   
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('_B.png') != -1){
            imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_B.png','_pt1.gif');
            $(this).attr('src',imgSrcToUse);
            return false;
        }
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('_pt1.gif') != -1){
            var POS2 = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif','_pt2.gif');
            var $that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:POS2,
                type:'HEAD',
                error: function()
                {

                    var imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt1.gif','_pt1.gif');

                    $that.attr('src','');
                    $that.attr('src',imgSrcToUse);

                    return false;

                },
                success: function()
                {
                    $that.attr('src','');
                    $that.attr('src',POS2);
                    return false;
                }
            });     

        }
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('_pt2.gif') != -1){
            var POS3 = imgSrc.replace('_pt2.gif','_pt3.gif');
            var $that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:POS3,
                type:'HEAD',
                error: function()
                {

                    var imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt2.gif','_pt1.gif');
                    $that.attr('src',imgSrcToUse);
                    return false;

                },
                success: function()
                {
                    $that.attr('src','');
                    $that.attr('src',POS3);
                    return false;
                }
            });     

        }
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('_pt3.gif')!=-1){
            imgSrcToUse = imgSrc.replace('_pt3.gif','_pt1.gif');
            $(this).attr('src','');
            $(this).attr('src',imgSrcToUse);
            return false;
        }

    });
```

you can see the site in action at http://schoolhousebalk.com/justin-upton/

any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would load them all at once and hide/show the images when clicked. If you load them onclick there will always be some kind of delay.

Comment: the thing about this is that i don't know how many images are associated with each graph. There could be one or two or three gifs. So on click I was checking if the next one existed, and if not, then reload the first one.

Comment: I checked your example quickly, I wouldn't suggest this if let's say there is thousands of images to load but if you have 20-30 images and the images are relatively small you could check on load on many exists, load the existing ones and place them inside a hidden division somewhere on your page. When the click occurs, you check inside the related hidden division the image to swap. Does it make sens?

Comment: yeah it makes sense. before i go through with this, do you know if a swap will cause the gif to load from the beginning each time? because if a swap is doing the same thing as replacing the source, then it's going to cause similar problems.

Comment: and by swap i mean a `show();` and `hide();` . i'm going to do some tests now.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, the gif might be playing in the background even if it's hidden, I've done this kind of things countless times with static images but not with animated gif

Answer (score 0):

Try preloading the new image before adding it to the `src` attribute. For example, instead of just `$(this).attr('src',imgSrcToUse);`:

```
var img = new Image();
var $el = $(this);
img.src = imgSrcToUse;
img.onload = function() {
    $el.attr('src', imgSrcToUse);
}
```